# How can I get user email with passport-google-oauth20

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am trying to implement user authentication using Node.js, passport, and passport-google-oauth20. All register/login handling works fine except it cannot retrieve user email (All other data like 'displayName' or 'provider' are successfully saved into my DB but not 'email').

Could anyone help me to get user email using passport-google-oauth20?

My code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/yourDB', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    displayName: String,
    provider: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/cb',
    userProfileURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo'
},
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        User.findOrCreate(
    { googleId: profile.id }, 
    { displayName: profile.displayName, email: profile.email, provider: 'google' }, 
    function (error, user) {
            return cb(error, user);
        });
    }
));

app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {  scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
);

app.get('/auth/google/journal',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/register' }),
    function (req, res) {
        res.redirect('/compose');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for 'emails' array instead of email. Please refer below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Hi, where did you get this screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Use profile.emails[0].value to get the user mail id and also ensure scope should have email

```
app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {  scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
);
```